# Create array of arrays of objects with var names

Tags: javascript

Here is my problem:

```
const data : [
{labelSlug: 'cola', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola'},
{labelSlug: 'cola', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola'},
{labelSlug: 'fanta', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola'},{labelSlug: 'activities1', category: 'activities', subCategory: 'activitiesSub1', provider: 'blabla'},
{labelSlug: 'activities2', category: 'activities', subCategory: 'activitiesSub1', provider: 'blabla'},
{labelSlug: 'equipments1', category: 'equipments', subCategory: 'equipmentsSub1', provider: 'blabla'},
{labelSlug: 'equipments2', category: 'equipments', subCategory: 'equipmentsSub2', provider: 'blabla'}
{labelSlug: 'cola', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola'},
]
```

I'm trying to get something like this for each category and subCategory:

```
{
  catering : [
    drinks : [
      { labelSlug: cola, provider: coca cola, count: 3 },
      { labelSlug: fanta, provider: coca cola, count: 1 }
    ]
  ]
}
```

The problem is I don't know how to set up this, I've tried all I could do:

```
const array = data.map((elem) => {
  const item = {};
  const sub = elem.subCategory;
  const cat = elem.category;

  // i've tried many things like that just to get everything in the right place (I didnt try to get the count part yet)
  // item[cat[sub]].labelSlug = elem.labelSlug;
  // item[cat][sub].labelSlug = elem.labelSlug;
  // item[cat[sub.labelSlug]] = elem.labelSlug;

  // const item = {
  //   [`${cat}`] : {
  //      [`${sub}`] : {
  //        labelSlug: elem.labelSlug
  //      } 
  //   }
  // }
  return item;
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired results, you'll need a more complex restructure of the result than what is possible with a simple `map` call (as this new structure will not be 1 to 1 mappeable with the current input)

```js
const data = [
    { labelSlug: 'cola', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola' },
    { labelSlug: 'cola', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola' },
    { labelSlug: 'fanta', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola' }, { labelSlug: 'activities1', category: 'activities', subCategory: 'activitiesSub1', provider: 'blabla' },
    { labelSlug: 'activities2', category: 'activities', subCategory: 'activitiesSub1', provider: 'blabla' },
    { labelSlug: 'equipments1', category: 'equipments', subCategory: 'equipmentsSub1', provider: 'blabla' },
    { labelSlug: 'equipments2', category: 'equipments', subCategory: 'equipmentsSub2', provider: 'blabla' },
    { labelSlug: 'cola', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola' }
]


const dict = {}

for(const entry of data) {
    const { labelSlug, category, subCategory, provider } = entry
    dict[category] = dict[category] || {}
    dict[category][subCategory] = dict[category][subCategory] || []
    
    let item = { labelSlug, provider, count: 1 }
    const index = dict[category][subCategory].findIndex(e => e.labelSlug === labelSlug && e.provider === provider)

    if(index > -1) {
        dict[category][subCategory][index].count++
    }
    else {
        dict[category][subCategory].push(item)
    }
}

console.log(dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to group the items by their `labelSlug` and all the other properties will be the same if the `labelSlug` is the same:

1. Create an empty object
2. Iterate over the array:
3. Create any missing objects/arrays
4. Find or create the object (with count 0 by default)
5. Increase count
6. Repeat

```js
const result = {}

for (const { category, subCategory, ...properties } of data) {
  result[category] ??= {}
  result[category][subCategory] ??= []
  const items = result[category][subCategory]

  let item = items.find(o => o.labelSlug === properties.labelSlug)
  if (!item) {
    item = { ...properties, count: 0 }
    items.push(item)
  }

  item.count++
}
```

Here you can see it in action:

```js
const data = [{
    labelSlug: 'cola',
    category: 'catering',
    subCategory: 'drinks',
    provider: 'coca cola'
  },
  {
    labelSlug: 'cola',
    category: 'catering',
    subCategory: 'drinks',
    provider: 'coca cola'
  },
  {
    labelSlug: 'fanta',
    category: 'catering',
    subCategory: 'drinks',
    provider: 'coca cola'
  }, {
    labelSlug: 'activities1',
    category: 'activities',
    subCategory: 'activitiesSub1',
    provider: 'blabla'
  },
  {
    labelSlug: 'activities2',
    category: 'activities',
    subCategory: 'activitiesSub1',
    provider: 'blabla'
  },
  {
    labelSlug: 'equipments1',
    category: 'equipments',
    subCategory: 'equipmentsSub1',
    provider: 'blabla'
  },
  {
    labelSlug: 'equipments2',
    category: 'equipments',
    subCategory: 'equipmentsSub2',
    provider: 'blabla'
  },
  {
    labelSlug: 'cola',
    category: 'catering',
    subCategory: 'drinks',
    provider: 'coca cola'
  },
]

const result = {}

for (const { category, subCategory, ...properties } of data) {
  result[category] ??= {}
  result[category][subCategory] ??= []
  const items = result[category][subCategory]

  let item = items.find(o => o.labelSlug === properties.labelSlug)
  if (!item) {
    item = { ...properties, count: 0 }
    items.push(item)
  }

  item.count++
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Well, I learned something new from this one! Cool use of [Logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment) (`??=`)

Answer (score 1):

Check out JavaScripts's [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method! It's kind of like the swiss army knife of array methods and you can use it to reduce or "transform" your array of objects into whatever you like!

```js
const data = [
  {labelSlug: 'cola', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola'},
  {labelSlug: 'cola', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola'},
  {labelSlug: 'fanta', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola'},
  {labelSlug: 'activities1', category: 'activities', subCategory: 'activitiesSub1', provider: 'blabla'},
  {labelSlug: 'activities2', category: 'activities', subCategory: 'activitiesSub1', provider: 'blabla'},
  {labelSlug: 'activities2', category: 'activities', subCategory: 'activitiesSub1', provider: 'blabla'},
  {labelSlug: 'equipments1', category: 'equipments', subCategory: 'equipmentsSub1', provider: 'blabla'},
  {labelSlug: 'equipments2', category: 'equipments', subCategory: 'equipmentsSub2', provider: 'blabla'},
  {labelSlug: 'cola', category: 'catering', subCategory: 'drinks', provider: 'coca cola'},
]

const organizedData = data.reduce((obj, curr) => {
  // the current item we're on in the loop
  const { category, subCategory, ...restOfData } = curr
  
  // if our accumulator obj has the category key and that obj[category] has the subcategory key
  if (category in obj && subCategory in obj[category]) {
    // check if obj with matching slugLabel is in the obj[category][subCategory] array
    const matchIdx = obj[category][subCategory].findIndex(o => o.labelSlug === restOfData.labelSlug)
    if (matchIdx > -1) {
      // if it is, increase the count
      obj[category][subCategory][matchIdx].count++
    } else {
      // if not, push a new object with a starting count into the obj[category][subCategory] array
      obj[category][subCategory].push({ ...restOfData, count: 1 })
    }
  } 
  // if obj does not have the category to begin with...
  else {
    // lets set a category key on the object with a starting and assign a subCategory key and array of items as the value
    obj[category] = { 
      [subCategory]: [{ ...restOfData, count: 1 }],
    }
  }

  return obj // must return the accumulator for each iteration of the loop to be used in the next run
}, {}) 

console.log(organizedData)

/* Result:
{
  "catering": {
    "drinks": [
      {
        "labelSlug": "cola",
        "provider": "coca cola",
        "count": 3
      },
      {
        "labelSlug": "fanta",
        "provider": "coca cola",
        "count": 1
      }
    ]
  },
  "activities": {
    "activitiesSub1": [
      {
        "labelSlug": "activities1",
        "provider": "blabla",
        "count": 1
      },
      {
        "labelSlug": "activities2",
        "provider": "blabla",
        "count": 2
      }
    ]
  },
  "equipments": {
    "equipmentsSub2": [
      {
        "labelSlug": "equipments2",
        "provider": "blabla",
        "count": 1
      }
    ]
  }
}
*/
```

*Edited answer to include a dups `count`.*

Comment: Thanks @CherryDT! Answer has been edited to remove dups and instead include a `count`.